# Glib linking error for g_socket_new

Tags: glib, gobject, gio

I am trying to learn glib and gObject for a networking project.

Here is the command used to compile (after using pkg-config to get output):

```
gcc socket1.c -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

socket1.c, after stripping, to identify the problem is:

```
 #include <glib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <gio/gio.h>

 static  GSocket *mySocket;
 int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   GError *err1 = NULL;

   mySocket = g_socket_new ( G_SOCKET_FAMILY_IPV4,
                 G_SOCKET_TYPE_STREAM,
                 G_SOCKET_PROTOCOL_TCP,
                 &err1);

 }
```

The error is:

```
  /tmp/ccKIEXOi.o: In function `main':
  socket1.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `g_socket_new'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried to use *readelf -Ws*  and *nm* to see if I could see g_new_socket in any of the .so files linked.  I did not see any. Is there a separate library I need to link to? Where/which is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to link to `libgio-2.0.so`, which is the third part of GLib (GLib, GObject, GIO). You can get its compiler and linker flags from `pkg-config` using `pkg-config --cflags --libs gio-2.0`.

You can tell `GSocket` is in GIO by looking at the documentation — it’s in the GIO manual: https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSocket.html.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that GSocket is in GIO but I thought that Glib includes GObject and GIO.

Comment: Nope, they’re deliberately kept separate since GIO is quite large, and lots of projects which use GLib for its basic data structures don’t want the more fully-featured I/O, networking and D-Bus support which GIO provides. GIO requires GLib and GObject. GObject requires GLib. GLib requires neither of the other two.